# Automating Website/Web forms using C# in Firefox, using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, firefox, selenium

If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it.

I'm working on a C# file in Visual Studio 2010 that I need to be able to test a website with multiple form pages, for the purpose of an example we'll refer to them all as 1.aspx, 2.aspx etc.

I've my code that fills out the first page (1.aspx) fine, and click the "continue" button to load the next page, but when it gets to 2.aspx it won't continue to fill out the form.

We'll say an element on the 2.aspx page is called "DOB". On trying to run from the start (I've all the pages form data in the one .cs file) I get an error like "DOB does not exist in the current context".

Anyone's insight into this would be really appreciated!

Comment: We'll need a see a copy of the page (HTML) and the code you are writing to see where things are going wrong. Either post it or upload it to gist.

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, it sounds like you might be better off using the [WatiN Framework](http://watin.org/).  I have been writing automation with it for years and the way that it is implemented and its ease-of-use make it worth the slight learning curve.

Just to add a bit more to the answer; and yes, this is pseudo-code:

```
[Test]
public void Should_attach_to_browser()
{
     ExecuteTest(browser =>
     {
          browser.GoTo(NewWindowUri);
          browser.Link(Find.First()).Click();

          var findBy = Find.ByTitle("New window");
          var newWindow = Browswer.AttachTo(browser.GetType(), findBy);
          newWindow.Close();
     });          
}
```

In the code above, note the `Browser.AttachTo(browser.GetType(), findBy);` method.  Based on what I have understood of your question, the `.AttachTo()` method would work well since you would be able to take the focus *off* the current form and assign it to the next in your work/execution flow.

Comment: -1 ...how on earth does that help? Both Selenium and Watin are very capable framework's, and both can easily accomplish what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: "Both Selenium and Watin are very capable framework's, and both can easily accomplish what the OP is trying to do" - Hence my suggestion of using them in the first place... Did you even bother to read the answer I gave, or the OP's question?

Comment: So your solution is to *completely* disregard his current framework and use something else? Brilliant.

Comment: I am not going to argue with you about this Arran.  If you don't like my answer, that is fine.  **She** asked for help, I gave the help she was asking for.  @ShaunaK, do some research as I suggested and if you like what you see with WatiN (it really is pretty well-designed), feel free to accept my answer.  I have been **very** satisfied with it, and found it to be much less verbose (in generated code) and more accessible than the built-in automation tools in Visual Studio (this is solely my opinion though).